# agregar texto a attr('src')

Tags: php, url, dominio

Hola soy novato pero estoy aprendiendo, tengo esta duda como puedo agregar texto al attr('src')

;$foto = $node->attr('src');});

Ejemplo:
;$foto = $node->attr('https://dominio.com/', 'src');});

**Razon:** cuando extraigo solamente el src, me extrae la extesion sin dominio.
**Asi**:      imagen/foto.jpg

**Y no asi:** https://web.com/imagen/foto.jpg

Por ello quiero agregar texto antes del 'src', pero si le pongo como lo puse me salta error, como se agrega correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

La preguntan no esta clara pero:
Asumiendo que lo que intentas es crear una varible `$foto` con el valor.

```
//Creas la urlbase

$foto = "https://dominio.com/";

//le agregas el path a la imagen

$foto .= $node->attr('src');


//resultado

https://dominio.com/imagen/foto.jpg
```